# Java: File.seperator is not recognized in Windows?

Tags: java, mysql

I have written a small J2EE web application in Eclipse IDE using WTP tools and Apache Tomcat7, running on Ubuntu 14.04, and then exported it as a .war file.
The application has a servlet that its sole purpose is to upload a picture from the client computer to the server, display it to the client, and then save the picture's url on a mysql data-table, for a later use.
When I startup tomcat7 and go to `http://localhost:8080/MyProject` in my browser to test the application, everything works perfectly fine.
The problem starts on Windows...
I wanted to test my application on Windows, so I switched to Windows, installed all the necessary programs (Apache Tomcat7, MySql...) and launched the app.
It worked on windows too, but(!), when the user upload a picture to the server, it will not display it correctly (instead all you see is the image you get from a broken url).
I then connected to MySql, to find out what url was saved in the MySql server, and found out that the file separator is missing.
Instead of: `userImages/userName/name_of_pic.jpg`, the mysql table holds `userImagesuserNamename_of_pic.jpg`...
Why is this happening? should I hard code the path like this?

```
File f=new File(userImages+"/"+userName+"/"+pictureFileName);
```

Because right now it is written like this:

```
File f=new File(userImages+File.separator+userName+File.separator+pictureFileName);
```

But it seems like it is ignored when it runs on Windows...

**Update:**

OK, I hard coded the path, and used the slash instead, and apperently, I was wrong... 
It is still not working, and ignores the separator, so `File.separator` is not the reason for the problem!
so my next best guess is the warning message I get when logging in to mysql through the cmd (command line):
[image]

Notice the warning: "mysql: unknown OS charachter set 'cp862'"... 
Could that be the reason?

**Update 2:**

Here's the code for saving the path:

```
public boolean setUserPicture(String firstName, String path, FileItemStream item) {

    File userPicturesFolder=new File(path+File.separator+firstName);
    if (!userPicturesFolder.exists()) {
        userPicturesFolder.mkdir();
    }

    File savedPicture=new File(userPicturesFolder.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+item.getName());

    try {

        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(savedPicture);
        InputStream is=item.openStream();

        int bytesRead=0;
        byte[] b=new byte[1024*10];
        while ((bytesRead=is.read(b))!=-1) {
            fos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    dataBase.editPicture(firstName,IUsers.imagesFolder+File.separator+firstName+File.separator+item.getName());
    return true;
}
```

and this is the code for he editPicture() function:

```
public void editPicture(String firstName, String filePath) {

    String command="UPDATE users "
            + "SET user_picture='"+filePath+"' "
            + "WHERE first_name='"+firstName+"';";

    try {
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(command);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error executing update: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

As I mentioned above, this code works in Ubuntu, after exporting it to .war file, but not in Windows...

Comment: First, windows can use the `/` so this change is unnecessary. Second, that's the file path you're constructing (where do you write to the Database)?

Comment: Did you try printing the output of "userImages+File.separator+userName+File.separator+pictureFileName" .That way you will know if there is something going on when you save the URL.

Comment: Looks like you are having when you are saving in DB , can you just print the path just before saving??

Comment: *Notice the warning: "mysql: unknown OS charachter set 'cp862'"... Could that be the reason?* No. No it could not. Please post the code where you save the path.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! edited the main post...

Comment: Please see my answer regarding usage of PreparedStatement. If you use Statement to update, you need to escape the backslash as part of the String.

Comment: You are making your life hard for no reason. Just use `new File(parent, child)` which works for both, parent `String` or parent `File`. There’s no need to create a mess like `new File(path + File.separator + firstName)` or even worse `new File(parent.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + child);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you do like this

```
String name = "abc"+ File.separator+"ABC";
```

It shall give you `abc\ABC`. If you insert this line in mysql it will store as `abcABC` using Statement

So you cannot insert backslash in mysql db. You need to escape your backslash try using double backslash `\\` or forwardslash `/`.

But I think the your `File f=new File(userImages+"/"+userName+"/"+pictureFileName);` should work fine

Or simply use `PreparedStatement` to solve the problem moreover `PreparedStatement` can avoid sql-injection too. So it is like add-on advantage

Comment: because Windows use \ (back slash) while Linux use / (forward slash) for File.separator

Comment: Oh... yeah, that makes sense, and is probably my problem.  
It didn't work when I used prepared statement, but I guess it is because I didn't use it right.. Thanks!